# How do I match data in SQL (cover rate)

Tags: sql, hana

I am having issues trying to match data in SQL... I would like to avoid using cursors or loops.

I have a table ConfigurationItems as such :

**Reference Table**

```
+----------+--------+-----+
| ConfigId | ItemId | Qty |
+----------+--------+-----+
|     1    |    A   |  1  |
+----------+--------+-----+
|     1    |    B   |  1  |
+----------+--------+-----+
|     1    |    C   |  1  |
+----------+--------+-----+
|     2    |    E   |  1  |
+----------+--------+-----+
|     2    |    D   |  1  |
+----------+--------+-----+
```

I have a temporary table where I store the data I need to compute :

**TempTable**

```
+--------+-----+
| ItemId | Qty |
+--------+-----+
| B      | 1   |
+--------+-----+
| C      | 1   |
+--------+-----+
| D      | 1   |
+--------+-----+
```

I need to find the matching ratio for each configuration (configId)
The key would be ItemId first, and then I should figure out how to integrate the Qty variable in the ratio.

Expected Result :

**Result**

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| ConfigId | Match %                                    |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| 1        | (nb matched ) / (tot compared) = 2/6 = 33% |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| 2        | 1/5 = 20%                                  |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Edit : I removed the qty part as it seems confusing

What I have tried so far :

```
do
Begin
create local temporary column table #reference (configId int, ItemId varchar(32), Qty int);
INSERT INTO #reference values(1, 'A',1);
INSERT INTO #reference values(1,'B',2);
INSERT INTO #reference values(1,'C',1);
INSERT INTO #reference values(2,'E',1);
INSERT INTO #reference values(2,'D',1);
INSERT INTO #reference values(3,'B',1);

create local temporary column table #tempTable (ItemId varchar(32), Qty int);
INSERT INTO #tempTable values('B',1);
INSERT INTO #tempTable values('C',2);
INSERT INTO #tempTable values('D',1);

SELECT ref.configID, Count(temp.ItemId),Count(ref.ItemId),  SUM(ABS(ref.qty - IFNULL(temp.qty,ref.qty))) as QtyDiff
FROM #reference as ref 
LEFT JOIN #tempTable as temp on temp.ItemId = ref.ItemId
GROUP BY ref.configID;
End;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY etc.

Comment: Where does the "6" come from for 1?

Comment: The 6 is the total elements compared (number of items in temp table + number of items for said configuration)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please edit your question and share the query that you used.

Comment: I updated with an example

Answer (score 1):

I find your logic a bit hard to follow.  You basically want conditional aggregation.  I think these are the two key umbers you want:

```
select r.configid,
       sum(r.qty) as total_qty
       sum(case when t.qty <= r.qty then t.qty else r.qty end) as num_matched_qty
from reference r left join
     temptable t
     on r.itemid = t.itemid 
group by r.configid
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actualy let's not worry about quantities in the first place, it might be confusing.

I already have issues counting how many itemId I matched... I updated the question.